# is setInterval slowing down my site

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I want to know if `setInterval` slowing down my site or not?

```
setInterval(function(){
    var uploadbtndiv = document.getElementById("imagesmaindiv");
    if (uploadbtndiv.childElementCount == 1) {
          document.getElementsByClassName("plusupload")[0].style.top = "17px";
    }else{
          document.getElementsByClassName("plusupload")[0].style.top = "-81px";
    }

}, 10);
```

Comment: what happens **if** you change the interval to 100, or remove the interval at all ... is your website faster? you can certainly make the code in the interval more efficient

Comment: Technically every operation is slowing down your website. Read about event loops

Comment: You should select each element *once*, not every time the interval runs. Also, `setInterval`'s minimum accurate "interval" is 12ms or 16ms or something like that IIRC, I think 10ms is too low

Comment: if `setInterval` slow down the site. and tell me why `setInterval` created by invertors of javascript?

Comment: @JaromandaX - Only very marginally, if `getElementsByClassName` is provided by the browser and not polyfilled. `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName` are both **blindingly** fast (the latter doesn't have to create a collection every time it's called; it returns the same collection every time).

Comment: setInterval is useful, setInterval 100 times a second with inefficient code is not what Brendan Eich had in mind

Comment: but, @T.J.Crowder getElementById only needs to run once, and since getElementsByClassName is a live list, it too only needs to be run once - so, I stand by my statement that the code in the interval can be "more efficient" (I didn't say significantly or even marginally faster :p )

Comment: @JaromandaX - And I didn't say you were wrong. I pointed out that it would be a *marginal* improvement.

Comment: fair enough - you're right in your answer though - `setInterval` is probably not at all the best solution for the "problem" at hand anyway - if you're potentially changing layout with every iteration, even requestAnimationFrame would be better than an interval (again, not in this case though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setInterval` doesn't slow down your site. Using it incorrectly can. In your code, you're scheduling an operation to happen roughly every 10ms. That's a lot. Even an efficient operation (and yours is tolerably efficient, though it could be more so) done 100 times a second can add up.

You probably don't want `setInterval` in your example. You appear to want to change where something is depending on how many elements there are in `imagesmaindiv`. I'd probably do that one of three different ways:

- By putting that `if`/`else` in the code that adds/removes elements to/from `imagesmaindiv`
- By using CSS, but it depends on the structure
- By using a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on `imagesmaindiv`, so I only do the work when its contents change instead of 100 times a second